# How write csv file without new line character in last line?

Tags: python, csv, python-2.7

I have a code like this to write csv file in python

```
import csv
with open('eggs.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ',
                            quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    spamwriter.writerow(['Spam'] * 5 + ['Baked Beans'])
    spamwriter.writerow(['Spam', 'Lovely Spam', 'Wonderful Spam'])
```

[image: output in image]

output shown in in image.
Now there is an extra line in output **(line 3)**. How can i remove  this last empty line while writing csv file.

Comment: The method writerow will append a newline to the end of each line written.  You need to use a different method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`file.seek`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#file.seek) to move file pointer before the last `\r\n`, then use [`file.truncate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#file.truncate).

```
import os
import csv

with open('eggs.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ',
                            quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    spamwriter.writerow(['Spam'] * 5 + ['Baked Beans'])
    spamwriter.writerow(['Spam', 'Lovely Spam', 'Wonderful Spam'])
    csvfile.seek(-2, os.SEEK_END) # <---- 2 : len('\r\n')
    csvfile.truncate()            # <----
```

**NOTE**: You should change `-2` if you use different [`lineterminator`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv#csv.Dialect.lineterminator). I used `-2` because  `\r\n` is default lineterminator.

Comment: 2021 and you saved my day. I do not know if newline='' in open works for Python3, but this in python 2.7 worked.

Answer (score 2):

here is a solution that removes the newline symbols from last line of csv, using rstrip:

```
def remove_last_line_from_csv(filename):
    with open(filename) as myFile:
        lines = myFile.readlines()
        last_line = lines[len(lines)-1]
        lines[len(lines)-1] = last_line.rstrip()
    with open(filename, 'w') as myFile:    
        myFile.writelines(lines)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('eggs.csv', 'wb',newline='') as csvfile:
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: Simple question simple answer - that's how programmers works.

Answer (score -1):

This code works on Python 3.6.7:

```
import csv
with open('eggs.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    spamwriter.writerow(['Spam'] * 5 + ['Baked Beans'])
    spamwriter.writerow(['Spam', 'Lovely Spam', 'Wonderful Spam'])
    # Delete new line at the end of csvfile:
    # It consists of 2 bytes according 'excel' Dialect, used by default in this case
    size = csvfile.truncate()  
    size = csvfile.truncate(size - 2)
```